# Maximize the carousel slider to the screen width

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

Is it possible to maximize the [carousel slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) to the screen width in flutter? Or, is it possible to use [PageView.builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) instead and autoplay it?

Comment: Can you include what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can get max screen to caresoule in flutter .
This is how you can get it.

```
CarouselSlider(
      options: CarouselOptions(
        viewportFraction: 1,))
```

Yes you can autoplay your page view builder with Future.delayed in flutter.
You can check an code example here for better understanding.

```
    Color myColor = Colors.orange;
List<int> list = [5,10,20];

Future fun ()async{
  for(int i =0 ; i  < list.length ; i ++){
    await Future.delayed( Duration(seconds: list[i]), () {
     setState(() {
       if(i  == 0){
         myColor = Colors.green;
       } else if (i  == 1){
         myColor = Colors.blue;
       }
       else if (i  == 2){
         myColor = Colors.yellowAccent;
       }
     });
    });
  }
}

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
       fun();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
            color: myColor),
    );
  }
```